# Как отредактировать .env в Docker?

Tags: telegram-bot, kotlin, docker, telegram

Нашел телеграм-бота на https://github.com/Heapy/kotbot

Установил для него докер на Debian по инструкции

Выполнил в терминале и стянул образ `docker pull heapy/kotbot:b52`

В инструкции сказано:

> 1) Используйте @BotFather для создания бота, который вы будете
>   использовать для тестирования;
>
> 2) Скопировать ./devops/.env-template-dev в ./devops/.envи заменить
>   id:secretс ботом лексем;
>
> 3) Запустите главное в io.heapy.kotbot.Application.
>
> 4) Вот и все, у вас есть запущенный бот.

Я не могу понять куда загрузился этот образ, что бы отредактировать .env файл. В случае с github я просто перешел бы в папку куда клонировал репозиторий, а тут как быть?
Помогите пожалуйста закончить установку бота.

Comment: Не вчитывался особо, но вы скачали образ, толку от него без контейнера -https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/
Попробуйте построить сначала

Comment: Спасибо что направили, буду пробовать

Comment: По сути вам попросту нужно переопределить переменные окружение на те, которые нужны вам. Можете это сделать при запуске контейнера. Если хотите запустить через compose - пропишите их в файл.

Comment: какой командой я могу поменять переменные?

Answer (score 0):

Напишу тут, тут больше места. 
Давайте последовательно.

Я стягиваю `docker pull heapy/kotbot:b52`

Дальше пытаясь запустить `docker pull heapy/kotbot:b52` справедливо получаю ошибку 
`Exception in thread "main" io.heapy.komodo.config.dotenv.EnvNotDefinedException: KOTBOT_TOKEN not defined.`

В документации пишут что .env-template-dev нужно скопировать в .env

Соответственно мы понимаем что эти переменные окружения нам следует передать.

```
KOTBOT_RELEASE=dev
KOTBOT_TOKEN=id:secret
```

Это можно делать как через  docker-compose (папка devops в github) и тогда вы можете свои токены прописать там, либо если мы запускаем непосредственно через `docker`, то с нужными переменными окружения запускаем так -

```
docker run -e "KOTBOT_TOKEN=aaaa" -e "KOTBOT_RELEASE=dev"  -ti heapy/kotbot:b52
```

Ну и справедливо получаем другие ошибки т.к. токен не валидный.

Ну и почитаем заодно [документацию](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) про переменные окружения в докере.

Ну или запускаете через docker-compose . Тем более что есть [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/Heapy/kotbot/blob/master/devops/docker-compose.yml) файл где вы попросту можете переопределить прям в нем нужные вам переменные окружения. 
Как работать с docker-compose тоже есть документация, уверен вы без труда найдете.